# Find a text using XLOOKUP

Tags: excel

I am looking for a way to find a text in a a excel using XLOOKUP (RECHERCHEX in french) and return the value of the next column.
My problem is that my text is defined using a '

[image: Example]
[image: Example]

For example if I want to search for C1 in the text, using `=RECHERCHEX("C1";C:C;D:D;"NOT FOUND";1)` it returns "B" where `C11, C101, C107, C109, C112, C119, C121` but it's wrong, I would like to get the value A where C1 is.

I tried everything

```
=RECHERCHEX("C1";C:C;D:D;"NOT FOUND";-1)
=RECHERCHEX("C1";C:C;D:D;"NOT FOUND";0)
=RECHERCHEX("C1";C:C;D:D;"NOT FOUND";1)
=RECHERCHEX("C1";C:C;D:D;"NOT FOUND";2)
```

Does not work.

Do you have any solution?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, why is `C11, C101, C107, C109, C112, C119, C121`? they are default or temporary, if only have `C11, C101, C107` then the value you need is B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=XLOOKUP("*, "&"C1" & ", *",", "&C:C&", ",D:D,"NOT FOUND",2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for a substring. It's not clear what you're looking for. If you want to find the first instance of C1 it would be in C5, because C1 is a substring of C143. Are you trying to find "C1," which is C1 with a comma after it? To search for C1 as a substring with no numbers following you'd need to do something more complex.

This will do what you asked for specifically, but will miss "C1" without a comma after:

```
=XLOOKUP("*c1,*", D3:D15, E3:E15, "not found", 2)
```